# Does Airflow v1.10.3 come with Flask App builder (FAB) by default and requires Google Oauth configs in webserver_config.py?

Tags: airflow, google-oauth, flask-appbuilder

I had a question related to Airflow v1.10.3. We recently upgraded airflow from v1.9 to v1.10.3. With the new upgrade, we are experiencing a situation where any Celery execute commands coming in from the UI are not getting queued/executed in message broker and celery workers.

Based on Celery FAQ: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-is-task-delay-apply-the-worker-just-hanging, it points to authentication issue, user not having the access.

We had web authentication (Google Oauth) in place in version v1.9 using following config:

```
[webserver]:
authenticate = True
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.google_auth
```

```
[google]:
client_id = <client id>
client_secret = <secret key>
oauth_callback_route = /oauth2callback
domain = <domain_name>.com
```

Will the above config values still work or do we need to set the RBAC=True and provide Google Oauth credentials in webserver_config.py?

**Webserver_config.py**

```
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH

AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Admin"

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [{
    'name':'google',
    'whitelist': ['@yourdomain.com'],  # optional
    'token_key':'access_token',
    'icon':'fa-google',
    'remote_app': {
        'base_url':'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/',
        'request_token_params':{
            'scope': 'email profile'
        },
        'access_token_url':'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
        'authorize_url':'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
        'request_token_url': None,
        'consumer_key': '<your_client_id>',
        'consumer_secret': '<your_client_secret>',
    }
}]
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, both will work. Of course, as they call the FAB-based UI, the "new UI", the old one will probably be killed off.

Your problem, though, doesn't sound like it has anything to do with **user** authentication, but celery access. It sounds like airflow and/or celery are not reading `celery_result_backend` or one of the other renamed options, when they should.
Search for `Celery config` in their [UPDATING](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/UPDATING.md) document for the full list.